# Centering on Stud.io (design software)

Tags: ldd, bricklink-studio

I'm trying out Stud.io for the first time and I am unsure how to centre a part I want.

I am used to just right clicking on the part to centre it on screen in LEGO Digital Designer, but this won't work on Stud.io as it just brings up options. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there: Right-click on a part. One of the options is "set as origin". This centers the view on this part. "Reset origin" does exactly that.

Otherwise, navigation is done by rotation (rmouse+move), panning (<kbd>space</kbd>+rmouse+move) and zoom (scroll).